# Error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, shell, rutas

Buen día, ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente. Tengo varios paquetes de Python2. Mi problema es que al ejecutar: ./catalogo.py

Tengo el error:

> #1: "Elemento sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado en la línea 3"

Código:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/sh
2 import sys
3 sys.path.insert(0,'/ruta_carpeta_paquete_y_modulos')
```

Al modificar el shebang:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/python
2 import sys
3 sys.path.insert(0,'/ruta_carpeta_paquete_y_modulos')
```

Obtengo el error:

> #2:"OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error".

Este último error hace referencia a un módulo donde invoco `subprocess.call`. Sin embargo, ya revisé que los parámetros sean correctos.

Yo creo que el problema está en el shebang, o en la manera en que estoy usando sys.path. No obstante, no he podido solucionarlo. ¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Comment: Prueba añadiendo shell=False en la llamada a subprocess.call Un saludo.

Comment: El shebang debe ser el del intérprete a usar con el script, por lo tanto debe ser la ruta al intérprete Python. Si usas `subprocess.call` para llamar a otro script debes indicar en el script invocado el shebang adecuado o especificarlo en explícitamente `subprocess.call`, algo como `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash','/<fullpathhere>/my_script.sh'‌​])`. Ten en cuenta que el primer elemento de `sys.path` suele ser la ruta del script que invoca al intérprete, normalmente se añaden las nuevas rutas insertando después de este y no en la posición 0, aunque depende de que pretendas conseguir por supuesto.